# Can't select individual account type in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I tried to start a free trial on GCP. But when I was entering credentials I accidentally closed the page. When I came back there is no option to make account as an individual anymore, only as a business. And I also still can't use anything like Compute Engine.

**Can't use Compute Engine to sign up:**

[image]

**No drop-down menu**
[image]

I tried starting a free trial in browser's private window. It didn't help. All ad-blocks are turned off

Comment: You can ceate a new google account to use free trial.

Comment: Did you try claring the cookies for google.com domain ? Or just try incognito window.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "entering credentials". The details do not make sense in the scope of how Google Cloud works to create an account. You need to authenticate first with Google Accounts (typically a Gmail / Workspace account) and then you can create an account/project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be [eligible for GCP free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) - in which case there are a few conditions:

> You've never been a paying customer of Google Cloud, Google Maps Platform, or Firebase.
> You haven't previously signed up for the Free Trial.

Seeing your case it looks like Google "thinks" you already signed up. Open up an incognito window (or [clear the cookies](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Cdelete-cookies-from-a-site) for google site) and try again:

- log in to your gmail account
- to to https://console.cloud.google.com/freetrial/signup

If you're unable to change account type try in another browser or on another computer.

If you're still stuck with the business account type you can report this issue on [Google's IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) and wait for help - however this may take some time depending on the issue.